# Notification Center iTunes widget bug?

Tags: itunes, notifications, widgets

Does the iTunes notification center (Today view) not display the track for live streams? Mine only shows for tracks in my library. In the case of live streams, it is simply blank. The main iTunes window, and mini-player, show the live track info just fine.
[image]